# extjs 4 tree select a specific node by two internal id

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

We can search a record in ExtJs 4 TreeStore by internal id using following code

```
var record = tree.getRootNode().findChild('id_name','XYZ',true);
```

Lets say I want to search a record where `id_name` should be `XYZ` and `age 10 10`.
**Do we have a method which allows user to search on more than one internal Id's**?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the id, whether it is called "id" or "id_name", must be unique for each node in the tree so there is always only one node returned by findChild and no other search condition is needed.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. What I meant was, Lets say the model which my store is using, have 4 properties, `ID, Name, Age, Salary`. Now I want to find `only one record` where Name is `XYZ` and Age is `20`.

Answer (score 0):

Use findChildBy here:

```
var record = tree.getRootNode().findChildBy(
    function(node) {
        return node.get('id_name') == this.requiredIdName && node.get('age') == this.requiredAge;
    },
    {
       // Putting the search criteria stuff in the context used for the function
       requiredAge: 10,
       requiredIdName: 'abc'
    },
    // true to do a deep search, false to search only on first level
    true
);
```